# Setting start node in a umbraco website

Tags: umbraco

I have this content structure for a multi language site.

- Content

  - Danish

    - Forside
    - Om os
  - English

    - Frontpage
    - About Us

When I start the website it automatically starts in the Danish-node, but I want it to start in "Forside", and as for the english part of the side I want it to start in the node "Frontpage".

The nodes "Danish" and "English" are page nodes as well, but are only there as a logical folder structure.

Is there any way I can choose which content node my website should start at?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the built-in feature:

1. Add a property called 'umbracoRedirect' to the document type associated with the 'Danish' node.
2. Set the property to be of type 'Content picker' and save it
3. At 'Danish' node set the property to point to node 'ForSide'.

That should work.

Answer (score 2):

Hey Peter, when doing Multilingual sites I tend to have the following structure

- mywebsite.co.uk

  - About
  - Contact
- mywebsite.com

  - About
  - contact

I then apply the host headers to the .co.uk and .com nodes with the appropiate language for dictionary item use.

I would make Forside/Frontpage the .co.uk/.com nodes that I have created in my strucutre as it seems like an unecessary level you have created.

Warren

Answer (score 0):

There is a way in umbraco for it to support globalization out of the box. You wont have to create 2 different trees of content.

[Umbraco Multilingual 1:1 Sites](http://www.umbraco.org/documentation/books/multilingual-11-sites)

Comment: 1:1 is not right in this case. We need different content structure in the english site.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple option that worked for me, although I accept it might not be suitable for everyone, is to Sort the root node. Umbraco seems to just use whatever is first in the content tree as the start page (v6.1.5 does, at least), and it seems to respect the sorting, so in this particular instance you would sort it so that 'English' logical container node comes before the 'Danish' logical container node.

Answer (score 0):

Umbraco choose the first site node as start-node. I suggest you to add a true/false field to your Site-Node document type named i.e. isPrimary, then in your codes you can find the sitenode having this field checked and navigate to it.